# Collection Updates in Methods

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have two collection update calls inside of a Method, which don't seem to be running at all.

```
Meteor.users.update({ _id: Meteor.user()._id }, { $push: { 'stars.teamStars': team.name } });
Teams.update({ _id: team._id }, { $inc: { stars: 1 } });
```

When I try to run the `Teams` update in the console it works correctly.
Although, when I try to run the `users` update in the console I receive `update failed: Access denied`.

I'm quite confused, as I have very similar update calls in other parts of my app, and they run perfectly.

Edit:
Should my Meteor.methods be located in `/server`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for `Meteor.users.allow` rules. You have removed the `insecure` package using (`meteor remove insecure`). This means you have to explicitly give meteor an allow rule for example:

```
Meteor.users.allow({
    update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
    }
});
```

Comment: If his code runs in a method, adding an allow rule should not be necessary (but you explain why the update call in the console doesn't work). To me it sounds like his method isn't running (called) at all, and by extension, nor the update calls inside it.

Comment: @PeppeL-G You're probably right, there might be an `err` given back by the method call instead which needs to be checked

Comment: I have a console.log within the method that is being called. So the method is being called. I'm so confused. I have very similar db calls that work. The only difference is that they aren't in a method. I'm going to run these outside of the method and see what happens. I can only assume they will work, but I need them to run in a method...

Comment: Are you running them on a client side method? Because they would end up as simulation stubs. They fill in the data on the client but dont really do anything. The reason they exist is they allow latency compensation so make it appear instant.

Comment: Btw if they're on server side methods the allow rules don't apply. Everything goes just as you tell it to

Comment: Client side method? I'm using Meteor.methods, which runs on the server, correct?

Comment: Also, I just tried running an update to the users collection from outside of the method, and I received an `access denied`. This is mind-blowing because just a few lines above it I'm running an almost identical update, which is working perfectly.